# Error :The game module could not be loaded

Tags: unreal-engine4

I started experimenting with game development and I am using UE4 . I am hosting my code on gitlab for version control.
I cloned my project from GitLab to my Ubuntu server, so I don't have to have a copy of it on every PC at home and I could work from the server, I get this error: "The game module "MyProject" could not be loaded. There may be an operating system error or the module may not be properly set up". I created the project on a Windows 10 machine. What should I do ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this solution doesn't work for someone, you can also check here, there is a more generic version of this error and a detailed answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77348549/the-game-module-x-could-not-be-loaded-there-may-be-an-operating-system-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the project in the *Windows* version of Unreal and you are trying to launch it in a Linux environment. That will not work.

Unreal compiles from source when you open the editor, so it will have to be set to build to Linux and not Windows.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well I enabled cross-platform compilation and I still cannot launch the project from my windows machine . If I run it natively on my server I works like a charm. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like that i created a project in Linux, then opened it in Windows Unreal editor then was unable to open it in Linux.
I resolved the issue by deleting Saved and Intermediate project folders. Now I can open the project in Linux Unreal editor.