# The game module 'X' could not be loaded. There may be an operating system error

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal

### Error Message

My project was working fine but after verifying my Unreal Editor install on the [Epic Games Launcher](https://store.epicgames.com/en-US/download) I'm receiving this error message when I tried to open my **Unreal Engine 5.3** project.

> The game module 'MyProjectName' could not be loaded. There may be an
> operating system error, the module may not be properly set up, or a
> plugin which has been included into the build has not been turned on.

What could happen after Verifying I don't know.

### I've already tried the steps below

- Open the project directory
- Delete these folders: Binaries + Intermediate + Saved and the [MyProjectName].sln file.
- Right-click on the [MyProjectName].uproject and select the “Generate Visual Studio project files” option
- And re-open the project

### Result

I am still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

I’ve some plugins in my project. And months ago I enabled them under some folder on my disk. I’ve already forgotten those. Probably you’re in the same situation.

#### Step 1

Go to the Plugins directory on your disk. For my current version, this is the directory on my disk:

```
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.3\Engine\Plugins\Runtime
```

#### Step 2

Find your mysterious plugin there, and open the directory. In my case, it was the HairStrands plugin.

```
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.3\Engine\Plugins\Runtime\HairStrands
```

#### Step 3

There is a file with the .uplugin extension, open with your desired editor of choice:

```
HairStrands.uplugin
```

#### Step 4

Find the **EnabledByDefault** word in the document. You’ll probably see it like below:

```
...
"EnabledByDefault": false,
...
```

#### Step 5

So, we need to enable that setting/s to be able to open our project again.

```
...
"EnabledByDefault": true,
...
```

**Solved!**

That solved the problem!

**⚠️ You've to **repeat** the process if you've more than one plugin.**

#### Step 6

Just re-open your project.

### Version

This issue is version-independent and exists in both Unreal Engine 4 and 5. Till version 5.3.

Hoping to see a solution in future releases.